# How do you create an apt-get package

Tags: apt, apt-get

I have a .out file for a project I am working on and I would like it available to download with an apt-get command. I wanted the apt-get command to be like `sudo apt-get install packageName`. I am using elementary OS, which is built off of Ubuntu. I also have the project posted on github.

Comment: I figured out how it went but not how to publish it

Comment: Well, if you ever figure out a list of steps to follow, I think many people will appreciate it if you posted it somewhere. You'll have my upvote at the very least!

Answer (score -1):

I think `equivs` is the easiest. You can install with:

```
sudo apt-get install equivs
```

With `equivs-control` command you can create a blank spec file and build your deb package with `equivs-build` command.